# Tents and Trees feasibility

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, puzzle-solver

Sequel to [Verify Tents and Trees solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/206786/78410).

### Background

**Tents and Trees** (try [here](https://www.brainbashers.com/tents.asp)) is a puzzle played on a square (or rectangular) grid, where the objective is to place tents horizontally or vertically adjacent to each of the trees, so that no two tents touch each other in 8 directions (horizontally, vertically, and diagonally) and the number of tents on each row/column matches the given clues.

#### Example puzzle and solution

In these examples, trees are `T` and tents are `A`.

```
Puzzle
  2 0 2 0 2 1
2 . T . T . .
1 . . . . T .
1 T . T . . .
2 . . . . . T
1 T . . . . .
0 . . . . . .

Solution
  2 0 2 0 2 1
2 . T A T A .
1 A . . . T .
1 T . T . A .
2 A . A . . T
1 T . . . . A
0 . . . . . .
```

### Challenge

Given a grid with some trees, determine whether it is possible to place tents next to each of the trees so that they don't touch each other in 8 directions. Ignore the number clues in this challenge.

You may take the input in any reasonable way to represent a matrix containing two distinct values to represent a tree and an empty space respectively.

You can choose to follow your language's convention of truthy/falsy, or use two distinct values for true/false respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

This uses the same notation as the above example; `T` for trees and `.` for empty spaces.

#### Truthy

```
. . .
. . .
. . . (empty board)

T .

. T .
. . T

. .
T T
. .

. T .
T . T
. T .

. . .
T T .
. T T
. . .

. T . .
. . . T
T T . .
. . . .

. T . . . .
. . . . . .
. . T . . T
. T . T . .
T . T . . .
. T . . T .
```

#### Falsy

```
(No space to place a tent)
T

T . T

T . T
. T .

. . . .
. T T T
T . . .

. T .
T T .
. T .

T . T
. . .
. T .

T . . . .
. . T . .
. T . T .
T . T . .
. T . . .

. . . . .
. T . . .
. T T . .
. . T T .
. . . . .
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me why `T . T` is Falsy? (I.e. why `TAT` is not a valid answer)  Is there a rule missing from the background, such as "There must be an equal number of Tents and Trees"?

Comment: @Chronocidal "Place tents horizontally or vertically adjacent to each of the trees," but that isn't fully clear. The [linked prequel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206786/verify-tents-and-trees-solution) states "The number of tents equals the number of trees,
The tents do not touch each other in 8 directions, and
There is at least one way to associate every tent with an adjacent tree in 4 directions, so that every tree is used exactly once."

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>253</s> 244 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
f=lambda b,h,w:all(set(t:=[i%w+i//w*1jfor i,e in enumerate(b)if e])&set(s:=[*map(sum,zip(t,T))])or~any(abs(a-b)<2for a,b in combinations(s,2))+all(h>a.imag>-1<a.real<w for a in s)for T in product(*[[1,1j,-1,-1j]]*sum(b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLRkpsgFH33Kxh2tgFD3HX70snEfewX8GacDhpsyCo4gOukD/31FNCo2Sk6eDncc@5Bbne1ZyW//@j07VZr1QJhubZKNQaItlPaxlGdNawtTwyU5EyGPWsaZLhFdp/l4nnYipeXIU4vtdJAEA6EBFz2LdfMclRiUQNe4G@eYBwhblmHTN@SP6JDllCMC6z0XyaviJUGsV2JD29eipHSS1WqLYVkVihpkCFvGG99/fM7S0TLfr/v0gNLNGfNYQCB5kkG@5D6sNPq1FcWxXmekvRCdql7L0UROw/OHca3ihluMghhAtwTreeI@ikBdEKoXyQOpeE77dCwM8YTkU6UKXPOvSs7mD6sl4Q1OMd0Io0RnWrMjJkbLNBosvQfZ3dXwcC68MpyshCTR@iLocXOYmY5RhStz0Afqi8ydH1adwlR1GkhLYJU9/Z83UMc@bv0l/TLWB1awl9YYrpGuLSjPEqI9xFww7XanJdlAFI44n5Mqkf5kzWGB90vlPy1CKynFatS0grZ8wA8jSLrGN3Jo1qVbfJ8A7azpuvMrmEV94UhgQXJIV6wxEGvZI1Qh6QOcRKbotgE0VIxfQIZ4J@sQdVYaCxeo/wjNL1Wg/8xY6YHPvzSoQUBDZcobOBV7M7qW/8f)

*-6 bytes thanks to @user202729 (chain comparisons)*

*-3 bytes thanks to @ovs (`1jfor`; `…or a+1^b` → `…or~a+b` for "implies" boolean operator)*

```python
# Itertools for combinations and product
from itertools import*
f=lambda b,h,w: all(
    # Test if a given set of tent position deltas works:
    # Positions are complex numbers: real part increasing to the right, imaginary part increasing down
    # (De Morgan shortened, so many expressions negated)
        # No tree is on a tent:
            # t:=Tree positions (1s)
            set(t:=[i%w+i//w*1j for i,e in enumerate(b)if e])
            # s:=Tent positions as sum of tree positions and deltas
            & set(s:=[*map(sum,zip(t,T))])
        # and difference between all distinct pairs oftrees is at least 2:
            or any(abs(a-b)<2for a,b in combinations(s,2))
        # and all trees are within rectangular boundary
            # (Using Python 2's quirky complex floordiv doesn't work since those return complex nums,
            # which don't have a total order.
            # Plus Python 38 has saves so much here; using 2 would be a waste anyway)
            >= all(h > a.imag > -1 < a.real < w for a in s)
    # For each possible delta (four directions, distance 1)
    # sum(b) is the number of tents since each tent contributes 1
    for T in product(*[[1,1j,-1,-1j]]*sum(b))
)
```

Comment: `w>a.real>-1<a.imag<h`?

Comment: @user202729 Ah, yes

Comment: Two tiny improvements: The space in `1j for` is unnecessary, and `+1^` can be replaced with `>=`.

Comment: @ovs That `1j for` is wholly unintuitive, but I guess it makes a bit of sense from a parsing standpoint.

Comment: One more: `or a>=b` can be `or~a+b`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 82 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⟦⟦⟧⟧θＦＬυＦ⌕Ａ§υιT«≔⟦⟧ηＦθ«υＦλ«Ｊ§μ⁰§μ¹A»Ｆ⁴«ＪκιＭ✳⊗μ¿›⁼.ＫＫ№ＫＭA⊞η⁺λ⟦⟦ⅈⅉ⟧⟧»⎚»≔ηθ»ＩＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDPS8MwFMfPzV8RenqBGBS8eSqbysTBwB6U0kPdsjUsTdY0mYL0b6@v6To0h4TvN@993o9tXbmtrfQwfNVKSworcwr@zTtlDsAY3YSuhsCpYg8k6zp1MFAUZclpi8beOgqv0hw8xmBw1E/K7DKtIfMrs5PfUzKnaZ5ixA9JZgoyamQkMamNX8kGy3pEoT35evKTl9CccntlNpzeIvOPvGMx6UJIszTKfubc/@ccp4HQWNuzhKVycuuVNbC04VPLHTTswlN7Cs9OVl46eGxDpTtIRcrpRsoj7ofThQ1YcJRra52EcVSsPq@uxlAdOtCcFsX7@PsBrCzZtb2FlpWDUfbX3dTTensyTbOoOj@vuR0bGwaRCzxEiMuDMid440viLUj0BBluzvoX) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as newline-terminated strings and outputs the number of solutions. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Read in the grid.

```
≔⟦⟦⟧⟧θ
```

Start with 1 solution for 0 tents.

```
ＦＬυＦ⌕Ａ§υιT«
```

Loop over the positions of the trees.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

No tent positions for this tree found so far.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the tent positions for the previous trees.

```
υ
```

Print the grid.

```
Ｆλ«Ｊ§μ⁰§μ¹A»
```

Print the tents for this partial solution.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Check the four orthogonal directions.

```
ＪκιＭ✳⊗μ
```

Move to the relevant adjacent square.

```
¿›⁼.ＫＫ№ＫＭA
```

If this square is empty and is not bordered by a tent, ...

```
⊞η⁺λ⟦⟦ⅈⅉ⟧⟧
```

... then append its position to the previous partial solution and add it to the list of new partial solution.

```
»⎚
```

Clear the canvas after testing this tree.

```
»≔ηθ
```

Save the new solutions as the current solutions.

```
»ＩＬθ
```

Print the final number of solutions.